# How to write a function max_and_min that accepts a tuple containing integer elements as an argument?

Tags: python-3.x

Functions can only return a single value but sometimes, we may want functions to return multiple values. Tuples can come in handy in such cases. We can create a tuple containing multiple values and return the tuple instead of a single value.

Write a function `max_and_min` that accepts a tuple containing integer elements as an argument and returns the largest and smallest integer within the tuple. The return value should be a tuple containing the largest and smallest value, in that order.

for example: `max_and_min((1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) = (5, 1)`

I am told to use an  iteration to loop through each value of the tuple parameter to find the maximum and minimum values. Also, I must use Python 3.x.

How do I do this? I am really clueless. Thanks for your help!

```
def max_and_min(values):
    # Write your code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to pass a variable number of arguments to a function. In python, you can get multiple arguments passed at invocation with the * notation:

```
def max_and_min(*arg):
    return (max(arg), min(arg))
```

Note that the Python 3 [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and max functions themselves accept a variable number of arguments.

Comment: *arg is correct if you want to invoke as max_and_min(1, 2, 3, 4, 5). arg is correct for the tuple example max_and_min((1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).